# Replace HTML attribute value with regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, onclick

I want to replace the HTML attribute double quote with single quote. For example:

If the input is:

```
<a onclick="Track("http://www.example.com")">Track Me</a>
```

The output will be:

```
<a onclick='Track("http://www.example.com")'>Track Me</a>
```

Here the `onclick="Track("http://www.example.com")"` needs to be replaced with `onclick='Track("http://www.example.com")'` i.e the only change here is `onclick="..."` is replaced with `onclick='...'`.

In my case the content is retrieved from an HTML editor whose content needs to be cleaned in client side using JavaScript. The only way I can currently think of is I need to use `Regex` to replace the **onclick** double quote attribute with single quote attribute and it should only happen when "Track" function is used in **onclick** attribute.

I have tried something like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FJ5g/2/)

I am looking for any solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there definitely no way to modify the editor to store it correctly?

Comment: The HTML is just **wrong**. Change the source with any editor you prefer.

Comment: The fact that you need to use RegEx to parse HTML means you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I think you should replace your logic.

Comment: @setec I don't think this counts as parsing HTML with regex - the OP doesn't want to extract any data, just correct it syntactically.

Comment: I agree with `setec`.  Can anyone help me to find out the regex to replace `onclick="..."` with `onclick='...'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cann't change others,then change yourself.
so here we go:

```
var str = '<a onclick="Track("http://www.example.com")">Track Me</a>';

console.log(str.replace(/onclick="Track\("([^"]+)"\)"/, 'onclick=\'Track("$1")\''));
```

Comment: Thanks. The Regex worked from me. I just modified it to: `/onclick="Track\("([\s\S]+)"\)"/`

Answer (score 0):

If You are still looking for regular expression, You can use this example. It will give You that link `<a onclick="Track('http://www.example.com')">Track Me</a>`

```
var s = '<a href="#" target="_blank" 
         onclick="Track("http://www.example.com/")">Test Link</a>';

var p = s.replace(/(onclick=")(.*)(\")/,function(match,prefix,handler,suffix){
    return prefix + handler.replace(/"/g,'\'') + suffix;
});

console.log(p);
```

And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukaszewczak/bhzFL/2/) for demo;

I did not see, that You look for version `<a onclick='Track("http://www.example.com")'>Track Me</a>`, so you can change above code with  this line

```
var p = s.replace(/(onclick=")(.*)(\")/,function(match,prefix,handler,suffix){
    return prefix.replace(/"/,'\'') + handler + suffix.replace(/"/,'\'');
});
```